# How to insert and retrieve picture in sqlite database in CN1

Tags: codenameone

I have challenges in fetching picture saved as bytes in sqlite database in codename one. Pls is there any special way in codename one to get picture from the sqlite database?

I am using this code

```
byte[] img = r.getBlob(0);
```

pls is their anythng wrong here?. I need a snippet code that will fetch pictures from the database. Bcos my pictures must reside inside database for better calling. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid that and instead store the data as a file as the blob functionality is flaky across platforms. Save the path to the file (or its name) in sqlite and store the files in storage or filesystem.

Comment: Do you have a demo for this Sir?  Because I will be calling the pictures with the ID from the sqlite. If you have the link for this you may send it to me sir. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Pls I need to pack my app with some images, which I need to be calling also

Comment: You can save images within your app either in a res file or within the src root. We don't have a demo of that.